# How to redirect page after click on Ok button on sweet alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am able to display sweet alert after the page refresh but I have to click on Ok button which I am getting on sweet alert to redirect the page.Please help  me in this.

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("WOW!","Message!","success");';
    echo '}, 1000);'
    echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide that `swal` function

Comment: @DININDU It's from the SweetAlert plugin. The tag has a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To specify a callback function, you have to use an object as the first argument, and the callback function as the second argument.

```
echo '<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        swal({
            title: "Wow!",
            text: "Message!",
            type: "success"
        }, function() {
            window.location = "redirectURL";
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>';
```

Comment: Thank you for reply Mr,Barmar, have you checked by code? I have to display that function in echo" " .Can you help me how write the code in echo.

Comment: There's no difference when you write it with `echo`.

Comment: code is working perfectly without echo but when i am inserting en echo its not working

Comment: I have to load sweet alert on page refresh. My code is working on page refresh but that ok button is not working.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Barmar, code is not working.Page is totally blank.

Comment: Add an update to your question showing the full code.

Comment: You're doing the redirect outside of the `swal()` function, so it doesn't wait for the user to respond.

Comment: Please help me how to do that because i tried your code but it's not working.

Comment: What is it doing wrong? Is it displaying the alert? What happens after you click OK? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Yes, Mr.Barmar. There were issue in my plugin.So i deleted and updated new one with your code and its working perfectly.I am really appreciate for you support and help. Thank you very much.You give me great solution.

Comment: Mr.Barmar, I have issue on sweetalert.Can you help me once again?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136597/how-to-use-sweetalert-to-display-variable-value-on-popup

Comment: Hello Mr.Barmar.One more issue in sweet alert.Please  please help me in this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754112/how-to-display-session-value-on-sweet-alert-popup/39754182?noredirect=1#comment66804612_39754182

Answer (score 86):

Just make use of JavaScript promises. Put the `then` method after `swal` function. We **do not** need to use timer features.
For example:

```
swal({
    title: "Wow!",
    text: "Message!",
    type: "success"
}).then(function() {
    window.location = "redirectURL";
});
```

The promise method `.then` is used to wait until the user reads the information of modal window and decide which decision to make by clicking in one button. For example, `Yes` or `No`.

After the click, the Sweet Alert could redirect the user to another screen, call another Sweet Alert modal window with contains new and subsequent question, go to a external link, etc.

Again, **we do not have to use timer** because it is much better to control user action. The user could wait for the eternity or take action as a Thanos' or Iron Man's finger snap.

With the use of promises, the code becomes shorter, clean and elegant.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Solved it for me! To fire swal I used: `Swal.fire({...}).then(function(){...});`

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `timer` build-in function, i.e.:

```js
swal({
  title: "Success!",
  text: "Redirecting in 2 seconds.",
  type: "success",
  timer: 2000,
  showConfirmButton: false
}, function(){
      window.location.href = "//this-person-does-not-exist.com";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
```

Comment: Mr.Pedro, have you checked by code? I have to display that function in echo" " .Can you help me how write the code in echo.

Answer (score 7):

Best and Simple solution, we can add more events as well!

```
swal({ title: "WOW!",
 text: "Message!",
 type: "success"}).then(okay => {
   if (okay) {
    window.location.href = "URL";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't able to do that with any swal(sweatAlert) default callback function, so I forced with jquery, got the Ok button class inspecting the element in chrome an made something like this:

```
<script>    
          sweetAlert({
                title:'Warning!',
                text: 'Invalid user or password!',
                type:'warning'
          },function(isConfirm){
                alert('ok');
          });
          $('.swal2-confirm').click(function(){
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
          });
</script>
```

The 'Ok' alert in function(isConfirm) was just a test to see if it would get into this function, if so I should be able to redirect from there, but I wasn't...

So I used jQuery to determine if the button "OK" of swal was clicked by getting it class: ".swal2-confirm' then I could redirect with success...

Hope this helps you all !

PS: I am using php echo to run the script, I din't have to leave php to run it, just use single quotes and you're done !

Comment: it's doesn't redirect

Comment: Inspect the element with chrome, probably, if it's not redirecting, it will return an error on the console. Also remember to add the sweetalert(and jquery) script and CSS properly.

Comment: *Correction: I was using an older swal files, just update to the newest one and the function should work, as @PedroLobito explained bellow.

Comment: I looked everywhere and nothing suggested worked until I saw this post; worked like a charm. Thanks. Only if I can this darn thing to work in IE. Anyone knows why the callback function is not executed?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone needs help, this code is working!

```
swal({
          title: 'Request Delivered',
          text: 'You can continue with your search.',
          type: 'success'
        }).then(function() {
            window.location.href = "index2.php";
        })
```

Answer (score 4):

```
                Swal.fire({
                    title: result.value.title,
                    icon: result.value.icon,
                    text: result.value.message,
                }).then(function() {
                    window.location.href = "url";
                })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me, I had to use **.then**

```
swal({
  title: 'Success!',
  text: message,
  type: 'success',
  confirmButtonText: 'OK'
}).then(() => {
  console.log('triggered redirect here');
});
```

Comment: .then is indeed the way.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me!!

```
<head>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</head>
<?php
echo "<script>
Swal.fire({
title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonText: `Save`,
denyButtonText: `Don't save`,
}).then((result) => {
if (result.isConfirmed) {
window.location = 'www.google.com';
} else if (result.isDenied) {
Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
}
})
</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('.delete-record').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.url = $(this).attr('href');
            swal({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
                padding: '2em'
            }).then(function (result) {
                if (result.value) {
                    console.log(window.url);
                    window.location.href = window.url;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please don't only share code, but also an explanation whats happening

Comment: for example
you have this a tag
<a href="/users/delete/1" id='delete-record'> delete </a>
so when this a clicked you will stop the event and shwo the swal whith confermation button and cancel button 
if ok button clicked you will redirect the user to the link in href att

Comment: perfect explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help. It's same as given by Mr. Barmer. But I have enclosed this within php tags.

Here it goes....

```
    <?php if(!empty($_GET['submitted'])):?>
        <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            swal({
                title: "Congratulaions!",
                text: "Signed up successfully, now verify your mail",
                type: "success",
                confirmButtonText: "Ok"
            }, function() {
                window.location = "index.php";
            }, 1000);
        });
        </script>   
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: This doesn't qualify as a good answer as the question has been answered already, you should've edited @Barmer's answer and updated it with PHP tags.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I'm sorry. I'm not well acquainted with asking and responding on this site, it won't happen anymore and thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
function confirmDetete(ctl, event) {

    debugger;
    event.preventDefault();
    var defaultAction = $(ctl).prop("href");
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will  be able to add it back again!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $.get(ctl);
                swal({
                    title: "success",
                    text: "Deleted",
                    confirmButtonText: "ok",
                    allowOutsideClick: "true"
                }, function () { window.location.href = ctl })

     // $("#signupform").submit();
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Is safe :)", "success");

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers did not work for me i just used `$('.confirm').hide()`. and it worked for me.

```
success: function(res) {
$('.confirm').hide()
swal("Deleted!", "Successfully deleted", "success")
setTimeout(function(){
window.location = res.redirect_url;
},700);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using this code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>

        $(".confirm").on('click',function(){
            window.location.href = "index.php";
        });

        </script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  setTimeout(function(){
Swal.fire({
  title: '<span style="color:#fff">Kindly click the link below</span>',
  width: 600,
  showConfirmButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#ec008c',
    confirmButtonText:'<span onclick="my2()">Register</span>',
  padding: '3em',
  timer: 10000,
  background: '#fff url(bg.jpg)',
  backdrop: `
    rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
    center left
    no-repeat
  `
})
  }, 1500);
}
function my2() {
 window.location.href = "https://www.url.com/";   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function in SweetAlert2, it worked for me.

```
swal({
    title: "Success!",
    text: "Example success message",
    type: "success"
}, function() {
     window.location.href = 'https://some-url';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
swal("Payment send successfully", "Thanks for using Npay!", "success")
.then(function() {
    router.push("/")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'Sukses',
      text: 'Password berhasil diset!',
      timer: 5000,
      showConfirmButton: true,
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        window.location.href = '/login';
      }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = '/login';
    }, 5000);
```

And this is the version for React.js Vue.js after 5 seconds it will automatically go to the page you are going to