# window.location.href not working with sweetalert

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating form using html and php,after submission of form i want to display success message with sweetalert and want to locate window to another page.I tried following code but but it is not working.Please tell me where i am going wrong

```php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
echo 'swal("Success!","Your complaint has been successfully registered.\n Your Customer Complaint No. is\n  "+"'.$complainno.'","success")
    .then( function(val) {  if (result.value) {
        window.location = "/cashier.php";
    }';             
echo '});';
echo '}, 200);  </script>';
```

Comment: try  window.location.href

Comment: please look into the `console` of web browser you may have errors

Comment: What is the actual outputted javascript? Inspect the source and see how it rendered. Check your console.

Comment: No, it is not working @Gulshan

Comment: change `echo '<script type="text/javascript">';`to `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";` Always try to use double quotes to echo and use singles inside echo

Comment: @Vishwa That doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: @Qirel, after submitting sweetalert is displaying but window is not locating to defined place

Comment: Inside your `then(function(val) {`, what is `console.log(val, result);`

Comment: @Qirel had experienced problems previously, just a side noted advice

Comment: A perfect solution is already available in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358423/how-to-redirect-page-after-click-on-ok-button-on-sweet-alert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
echo '<script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            swal({
                title: "Success!",
                text: "Your complaint has been successfully registered.Your Customer Complaint No. is"+$complainno,
                type: "success"
            }, function() {
                window.location.href = "cashier.php"; // window.location also can be used
            });
    }, 1000);
</script>';
```